# How do I show drop down list item selected in an alert?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with text fields, a drop down list, radio buttons, and text boxes. I would like to show all user input from the form in an alert. This was working before but then I was required to add the drop down menu. Now, upon clicking submit no alert shows up. I would like the alert to print out all information entered into the form by the user, including the selection from the drop down menu.
This is what I have:

```
<html>

<!--nff Add a title to the Web Page.-->

<head>
<title>Pizza Order Form</title>
<script>

/*nff Add the doClear function to clear the information entered by the user and enter the information to be cleared when the clear entries button is clicked at the bottom of the Web Page.*/

function doClear()
{
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
elements[0].value = 'PA';

  document.PizzaForm.customer.value = "";
  document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
  document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
  document.PizzaForm.zip.value = "";
  document.PizzaForm.phone.value = "";
  document.PizzaForm.email.value = "";

  document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;

  document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;
  return;
}

//nff Add a doSubmit button to indicate what the outcome will be when the user clicks the submit order button at the bottom of the form.
function doSubmit()


/*nff Add an if statement to the doSubmit function to return false if there is missing information in the text fields once the user clicks the submit order button.*/

{
  if (validateText() == false) {
    return false;
  }

//nff Add an if statement to the doSubmit function to return false if there is no pizza size selected using the radio buttons.

  if (validateRadio() == false) {
    return false;
  }

//nff Add an if statement to the doSubmit function to return false if there are no toppings selected using the checkboxes.

  if (validateCheckbox() == false) {
    return false;
  }

//nff Add an if statement to the doSubmit function to return false if the email entered by the user is empty or does not fit the acceptable format.

  if (validateEmail() == false) {
    return false;
  }

/*nff Add an if statement to the doSubmit function to return false if the phone number entered by the user is empty or does not fit the acceptable formats.*/

  if (validatePhone() == false) {
    return false;
  }

//nff Add an alert box to show customer information from text fields when the Submit Order button is clicked.

  var customer = document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
  var address = document.PizzaForm.address.value;
  var city = document.PizzaForm.city.value;
  var state = document.PizzaForm.state.value;
  var zip = document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
  var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
  var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;

  var size = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < document.PizzaForm.sizes.length; i++) {
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].checked) {
      size = document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
      break;
    }
  }

  var toppings = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < document.PizzaForm.toppings.length; i++) {
    if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked) {
      toppings.push(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim());
    }
  }

  alert("Name: " + customer + '\n' +
    "Address: " + address + '\n' +
    "City: " + city + '\n' + 
    "State: " + state + '\n' +
    "Zip: " + zip + '\n' +
    "Phone: " + phone + '\n' +
    "Email: " + email + '\n' +
    "Size: " + size + '\n' + (toppings.length ? 'Toppings: ' + toppings.join(', ') : ''));
}

//nff Add the validateText function to ensure that all text fields are complete before the order is submitted.

function validateText() {
  var customer = document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
  if (customer.length == 0) {
    alert('Name data is missing');
    document.PizzaForm.customer.focus();
    return false
  };
  var address = document.PizzaForm.address.value;
  if (address.length == 0) {
    alert('Address data is missing');
    return false;
  }
  var city = document.PizzaForm.city.value;
  if (city.length == 0) {
    alert('City data is missing');
    return false;
  }
  var zip = document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
  if (zip.length == 0) {
    alert('Zip code data is missing');
  } else if (zip.length < 5) {
    alert('Invalid zip code data');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
  if (phone.length == 0) {
    alert('Phone data is missing');
    return false;
  }
  var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
  if (email.length == 0) {
    alert('Email data is missing');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

//nff Add the validateRadio function so that if none of the radio buttons for pizza size are selected it will alert the user.

function validateRadio() {
  if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked) return true;
  alert('Size of pizza not selected');
  document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].foucs();
  return false;
}

//nff Add the validateCheckbox function so that if none of the checkboxes for toppings are selected it will alert the user.

function validateCheckbox() {
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked) return true;
  if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked) return true;
  alert ('Toppings are not selected');
  return false;
  }

//nff Add the validateEmail function to ensure that the email address has been entered in the correct format.

function validateEmail() {  
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{3,4})+$/.test(PizzaForm.email.value))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  }  
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address")  
    return (false)  
} 

//nff Add the validatePhone function to ensure that the phone number has been entered in any of the acceptable formats.

function validatePhone() {
  if (/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/.test(PizzaForm.phone.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid phone number")
    return (false)
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!--nff Add a form for the user to enter information into.-->

  <form name="PizzaForm">

<!--nff add a title at the top of the Web Page-->

  <h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h1>

<!--nff add directions to the user for the information to be entered-->

  <p>
  <h4>Step 1: Enter your name, address, and phone number:</h4>

<!--nff change the font-->

  <font face="Courier New">

<!--nff insert a text field for user to enter their name, add spaces between the title of the text box and the box itself, specify the size of the input box, and the type of input into the box as text.-->
<form>
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>

<!--nff insert a text field for user to enter their address, specify the size of the input box, and the type of input into the box as text.-->
Address: <input name="address" size="50" type="text"><br>

<!--nff Insert a text field for user to enter their city, add spaces between the title of the text box and the box itself, specify the size of the input box, and the type of input into the box as text.-->
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="city" size="15" type="text">

State:<select>
          <option selected value="PA">PA</option>
          <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
          <option value="NY">NY</option>
          <option value="DE">DE</option>
      </select>

Zip: <input name="zip" size="5" type="text"><br>

<!--nff Insert a text field for the user to enter their phone number, insert spaces after the title of the box, specify the size of the box, and the type of input as text.-->
    Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="phone" size="50" type="text"><br>

<!--nff Insert a text field for the user to enter their email address, insert spaces after the title of the box, specify the size of the box, and the type of input as text.-->
    Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="email" size="50" type="text"><br>
  </font>
 </p>

 <!--nff add second step to order a pizza-->
 <p>
   <h4>Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
   <font face="Courier New">

<!--nff Add radio buttons to choose from four options for pizza sizes.-->
     <input name="sizes" type="radio">Small
     <input name="sizes" type="radio">Medium
     <input name="sizes" type="radio">Large
     <input name="sizes" type="radio">Jumbo<br>
   </font>
 </p>
 <p>

  <!--nff add third step to order a pizza-->

   <h4>Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
   <font face="Courier New">

<!--nff Add check boxes for user to choose toppings.-->
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Pepperoni
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Canadian Bacon
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Sausage<br>
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Mushrooms
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Pineapple
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Black Olives<br>
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Green Peppers
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">Extra Cheese
     <input name="toppings" type="checkbox">None<br>
    </font>
   </p>

 <!--nff Add buttons for the options to submit order or clear entries. Add an onClick event to show one of the alerts entered earlier in this document when the submit button is clicked at the bottom of the Web Page. Add and onClick event to clear the entries in this form upon clicking the clear entries button.-->
   <input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
   <input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that means there is a js error, check the console window from development tools

Answer (score 1):

Please show your HTML/Form also. 
Please read about the `.selectedIndex` property for drop-down list.
One quick link below:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: I added the HTML above. It was long so I showed just a small section last time. I can see how the example shown in the link you posted works on the w3schools site however, I can not get it to work for me. I have other form data to show in the alert as well and I'm not sure where to add what's shown in the link. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your < select > has no name, so when you are trying to retrieve the value of state, you get nothing.

Try this:

```
<select name="state">
      <option selected value="PA">PA</option>
      <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
      <option value="NY">NY</option>
      <option value="DE">DE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just took this suggestion but there must be something else missing because it is still not showing the alert with all of the user's input when I click the submit button.

Comment: I feel like I have tried everything and I am stuck. Can anyone help? What am I missing?

Comment: I also noticed that your radio buttons have no value, so you should add "value='yourValue'" to all of them. The same goes for your checkboxes.

Comment: I added a value to each radio button and checkbox. Before doing so, I was able to get the drop to input to print in the alert with the rest of the input. I haven't noticed a difference since adding the value to the radio buttons and checkboxes. What is the purpose/importance of doing so?

Comment: you need to add names to them so that you can retrieve their value. if your radio buttons e.g. do not have value, then `document.PizzaForm.sizes.value` will equal nothing, even though a radio button is checked. This also applies to the checkboxes, however, the value for the checkboxes are retrieved from an array. Doing it this way will save you alot of time when trying to retrieve the checked values.